# how to use available skins in flex

Tags: apache-flex

How to use the skins shown on various sites e.g
[flex skin site](http://ntt.cc/2010/05/11/40-beautiful-themes-skins-for-adobe-flex-apps.html)
into my flex project. Please help.

Comment: @Mat I could not find links to any tutorials on that site that answer the question.  Can you provide it?

Comment: I gave this a +1 because I think the question "How do I use a Flex Skin" is perfectly valid.  I see the site that the poster links to includes tutorials on how to create skins; but nothing on how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source for one of the samples.

[Start here](http://ntt.cc/ext/Themes-Skins-For-Adobe-Flex/demo/Aeon/Aeon.html#) to load the first sample.

Then right click and select "View Source" from the context menu, to [bring up the source](http://ntt.cc/ext/Themes-Skins-For-Adobe-Flex/demo/Aeon/srcview/index.html).

You'll see this line of code in the main application file:

```
<mx:Style source="AeonGraphical.css" />
```

And that is how you include a css file in a Flex application.

Depending on the content of the CSS file; Flex may pick up the design automatically.  Or you may have to specify a styleName on individual components.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can use the css by using the method you have suggested. But I was looking for a skin which I can directly use using something like skinClass = "customSkin". I am a beginner, and would be pleased if you could guide me through

Comment: It all depends how you create the styles in your CSS file.  Read this portion of the docs which should include more info: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fee.html

Comment: The skins on the site given by me in the question are for flex 3. How to use them in flex 4. I tried copying the css file and the swc files to my project. But its not working. Also tried editing the css file. But it didnt work.

Comment: You can use them in Flex 4 the same way I Specified.  However, I doubt they include skins for Flex 4 Spark components.  so, you'll have to create your own, possibly by converting the ones you downloaded in some manner.